# TYPO3 Gridelements 10 - Gridelement Link Wizard Flexform

Tags: typo3-10.x, flexform, tx-gridelements

In older versions I used the following Flexform to integrate an anchor field with link wizard in custom gridelements. Since v10 it doesn't work anymore. It's like a normal input field, but the wizard at the end of the field is missing. Any ideas how to adjust the Flexform to get the wizard back?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
  <meta type="array">
    <langDisable>1</langDisable>
  </meta>
  <ROOT type="array">
    <type>array</type>
    <el type="array">

<anchor type="array">
    <TCEforms type="array">
      <config type="array">
        <type>input</type>
        <eval>trim</eval>
        <wizards type="array">
          <_PADDING>2</_PADDING>
          <link type="array">
            <type>popup</type>
            <title>Link</title>
            <icon>link_popup.gif</icon>
            <module type="array">
              <name>wizard_element_browser</name>
              <urlParameters type="array">
                <mode>wizard</mode>
                <act>file</act>
              </urlParameters>
            </module>
            <params type="array">
              <blindLinkOptions></blindLinkOptions>
            </params>
            <JSopenParams>height=300,width=500,status=0,¬menubar=0,scrollbars=1</JSopenParams>
          </link>
        </wizards>
      </config>
      <label>Link</label>
    </TCEforms>
 </anchor>

</el>
</ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution!

You have to change `<type>input</type>` to `<type>inputLink</type>`, then everything works fine.